# InnoDB not locking a SELECT statement using db_query()

Tags: database, 6

From [Any way to select without causing locking in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917640/any-way-to-select-without-causing-locking-in-mysql/918092) I found a way to implement a select query in a InnoDB table without locking.

The example code given there is the following.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME ;
COMMIT
```

If I want to implement a similar statement using `db_query()`, can I do so by issuing three consecutive calls like the following code?

```
db_query("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED")
db_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME")
db_query("COMMIT")
```

`db_query()` doesn't support multi-line statements, on Drupal 6.

Comment: _can I do so by issuing three consecutive calls like this_ What happened when you tried it?

Comment: The query worked. But I am not sure if a lock was set or not. I am not that good at mysql/php internals and hence unable to determine whether three different db_query calls will still count as a transaction to mysql.